# Need some guidance adding iOS app to phonegap

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have a simple iPhone game, but I'd like to know if it's possible to add it to phone gap. I don't want the app to be installed from iTunes, but to be used from the web, plus I don't have iTunes account to add it there.

Thanks

Comment: How have you written your game? Is it native Objective-C or is it JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have written your game in Objective-C. However, when developing with PhoneGap you use the web languages HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Therefore, you would need to rewrite your whole code. I would rethink that desicion though as you won't reach the same level of performance with JS compared to Objective-C.

Comment: Its written in Objective-C. I taught there may be some way of implementing the app so to speak with phone gap so it can be used from the we, just to add bookmark on your home screen.

Comment: I noticed that there are tools to convert PhoneGap apps to native iOS apps. Do you guys know any tools that can could do the opposite? That would be easy ad save some time.